# Printing in Java 1.5, slow?

Tags: java, printing, attributes

I'm using the following code to print in Java 1.5, however the time it takes to send the print job to the printer is average 35-40 sec. It's spending the time on the following line: printJob.print(attrSet);

Is there a way to speed this up?

```
private void print() {
     PrintRequestAttributeSet  attr;
     attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();   
     attr.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);  
     MediaSize mediaSize =
             MediaSize.getMediaSizeForName(MediaSizeName.NA_LEGAL);
     float[] size = mediaSize.getSize(MediaSize.INCH);
     attr.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, size[0], size[1],
                     MediaPrintableArea.INCH));

    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintable(this);
    if (printJob.printDialog())
        try {
            for (Component cmp : componentsToBePrinted) {    
                this.componentToBePrinted = cmp;
                printJob.print(attrSet);
            }
        } catch(PrinterException pe) {
            System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
        }
}
```

Comment: Printing in general is slow. Just like with any system resource, it's likely a blocking operation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the printer driver. Adjust the printer driver to PCL from PS.
This helped us with printing on XEROX-Printers.
This speed up to 1 second.